# How to access aliased attributes in ActiveRecord class? Is there a better way I'm missing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm interfacing with an older database and have mapped the old column names to the new ones using `alias_attribute`.

It works great, but I also want to get a list of all the attributes for a record too. Using `record.attributes` only gives me the original attributes, not the aliased ones too. Is there a way I can list all these through a similar method?

Maybe I would be better off just making a lookup hash?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Rails 5.0.7.2 or possibly earlier:

```
ModelClass.alias_attribute :new_name, :old_name

#=> [a heap of ActiveModel::AttributeMethods::ClassMethods::AttributeMethodMatchers]

ModelClass.attribute_aliases

#=> {"new_name"=>"old_name"}

ModelClass.attribute_alias(:new_name)

#=> "old_name"
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid it isn't possible to get the list of aliased attributes. The `alias_attribute` method does nothing beyond creating few getters/setters. This method doesn't "mark" these methods in any way.

Comment: Out of date now – this is possible after all